# How to reassign to an .on event after turning it off with the .off function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a link I click:

```
$('nav').on('click', 'a', function(){...};
```

Inside an ajax request in `beforeSend` I unsubscribe from the event with

```
beforeSend: function(){
        $('nav').off('click', 'a');
      },
```

Is it possible to re-subscribe to the event in success again?

```
success: function(response){
//Subscribe to click event here again
      },
```

Comment: Store a reference to the function in an appropriately-scoped variable and (un)subscribe exactly that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution to this is to call the same on-click event handler recursively inside the ajax request. I'll provide the complete code for this one.

```
  function recursiveClickHandler(){
      var page = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      var remove=$(".injectedPage");
      $.ajax({
        url: page,
        type:'GET',
        beforeSend: function(){
          $('nav').off('click', 'a');
        },
        success: function(){
          $('nav').on('click', 'a', recursiveClickHandler);
        }
      });
  }
  $('nav').on('click', 'a', recursiveClickHandler);
```